# Are there any drawbacks to creating ext4 file systems with maximum inodes?

Tags: filesystem, ext4, inode

Are there any drawbacks to creating ext4 file systems with 2^32-1 inodes?

I have a 1tb drive and I would like to store 800 million to 1.5 billion small files on it. It seems that the max is 4 billion, so I'm wondering whether I could just set it to the max when creating an fs, or I should find some other solution.

Comment: Each ext4 inode takes up 250 bytes of disk space ...

Comment: @SorenA, even if it's unused?

Comment: If size of single inode is  smaller than the blocksize of the filesystem, then in that case more inodes would be made than can ever be used.

Comment: @PerlDuck, please see edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to similar questions over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) 
and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) (see below) it is a bad idea
to max out the number of inodes on an ext4 filesystem.

Better use another filesystem or split your disk into multiple filesystems.

To summarize:

- An inode occupies 256 bytes. It may be configured to 128, but even though:

  ```
  2³² inodes × 256 bytes each = 1 TB
  ```
- When creating an ext4 filesystem, you can specify the *usage type*
  as defined in `/etc/mke2fs.conf`:

  ```
  mkfs.ext4 -T usage-type /dev/something
  ```

  For storing many small files the type `small` might be used:

  ```
  small = {
      blocksize = 1024
      inode_size = 128
      inode_ratio = 4096
  }
  ```

  This means: for every 4096 bytes of diskspace (filesystem size) one inode will be reserved
  each of which has a size of 128 bytes. The command `mkfs.ext4 -T small /dev/something`
  would thus create 244 million inodes on a 1TB filesystem that occupy 31 GB. These
  244 million files will at least occupy 250 GB (min. 1024 bytes each).
- To hold 1 billion inodes with the small footprint (128 bytes) you would need 128 GB 
  just for the inodes. If the smallest possible blocksize (1024 according to mk2efs's 
  manpage) is used, then these 1 billion files would at least occupy 1TB (but remember
  you only have 872 GB left because of the 128 GB for the inodes).
- The smallest possible blocksize for ext4 is 1024 bytes. Hence, you cannot store more than
  1 TB / 1024 = 1 billion files and it's pointless to have more inodes.
- As a general rule of thumb the `inode_ratio` should not be smaller than the `blocksize`
  because you cannot (easily) store more than one file in one block.
- It is possible to store the first 60 bytes of a file directly whithin the inode if the
  filesystem is configured that way. In that case, the file would not occupy a (regular)
  block; read about such [inline data here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data_2) but also consider the [inode size](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Size).
- From a comment to the [U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74451/251553):

  > Too many inodes has a deep cost for sure, they take up space themselves, and believe me that fsck performance is dead serious. We're talking practically exponential slowdowns, like 30 seconds vs 2 days... and this is I/O bound. Not to mention slow downs of file listing, indexing... etc.

---

References:

- [How to store one billion files on ext4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21397110/5830574)
- [Drawbacks of increasing number of inodes in EXT4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74451/251553)
- [Ext4 Disk Layout](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout)
- [Smallest file block size (ext 3, 4)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191324/251553)